# jQuery localScroll only working in IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following jQuery code that uses the scrollTo and localScroll plugins from [Ariel Flesler](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html)  :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#navigation').localScroll({
        target: '#scrollpane',
        queue: true,
        duration: 1500
    });

});
```

I have the following CSS:

```
#scrollpane {
height: 400px;
width: 950px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

And the following markup:

```
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li>
            <a href="#smallgallery" title="Small Studio">Small<br/><span>SMALL STUDIOS</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#mediumgallery" title="Medium Studio">Medium<br/><span>MEDIUM STUDIOS</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#largegallery" title="Large Studio">Large<br/><span>LARGE STUDIOS</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

<div id="scrollpane">
    <div id="smallgallery">
        <img class="img" src="/content/img/gallery-holder.jpg" width="946" height="398" alt="Gallery Image" />
        <img class="img" src="/content/img/gallery-holder.jpg" width="946" height="398" alt="Gallery Image" />
        <img class="img" src="/content/img/gallery-holder.jpg" width="946" height="398" alt="Gallery Image" />
        <img class="img" src="/content/img/gallery-holder.jpg" width="946" height="398" alt="Gallery Image" />
    </div>

    <div id="mediumgallery">
        <img class="img" src="/content/img/gallery-holder.jpg" width="946" height="398" alt="Gallery Image" />
        <img class="img" src="/content/img/gallery-holder.jpg" width="946" height="398" alt="Gallery Image" />
        <img class="img" src="/content/img/gallery-holder.jpg" width="946" height="398" alt="Gallery Image" />
        <img class="img" src="/content/img/gallery-holder.jpg" width="946" height="398" alt="Gallery Image" />
    </div>

    <div id="largegallery">
        <img class="img" src="/content/img/gallery-holder.jpg" width="946" height="398" alt="Gallery Image" />
        <img class="img" src="/content/img/gallery-holder.jpg" width="946" height="398" alt="Gallery Image" />
        <img class="img" src="/content/img/gallery-holder.jpg" width="946" height="398" alt="Gallery Image" />
        <img class="img" src="/content/img/gallery-holder.jpg" width="946" height="398" alt="Gallery Image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine in IE7 only and doesnt work in any other browsers including FF, IE8 and Chrome etc!? all it does is move a couple of PX and stops

Anyone seen this before or have any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try making `overflow: hidden;` and change it to `overflow: auto;`